# Within the Microsoft Enterprise Framework, where did the FormatterData.GetRegistrations method go?

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, msdn, enterprise-library-6

I have the unforuntate task of upgrading some decade old C# code that uses the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging` library. I've almost gotten it to compile with just one error left:

They are extending the FormatterData abstract class, which is provided by `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration`. [MSDN includes the (minimal) docuemntation for this class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.configuration.formatterdata(v=pandp.50).aspx). This includes the alleged method [GetDetails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.configuration.formatterdata.getregistrations(v=pandp.50).aspx). The code overrides this method. However, my copy of the library does not feature that method. I have downloaded the latest copy of the library (Version tag: "6.0.0.0"). I don't have a copy of the dll the original author was working with.

I can only assume that the method was removed, and I probably need to download some historical copy of the library. However, the MSDN articles (as far as I can see) do not indicate where these methods were added or removed. Which version of the library do I need to use and where might I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By rolling back the version of EnterpriseLibrary.Common and EnterpriseLibrary.Logging in NuGet I found that version 5.0.505 is the last version with the required method.